# Is it possible to install a new Kernel on an OS I can't boot into?

Tags: debian, boot, kernel, kernel-panic

I just installed Debian onto an SD card via my laptop. I have now moved that SD card to my server and tried to boot from it. The error it's giving me is:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on this CPU:
cmov
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for this CPU.
```

Is this Debian install doomed? Do I have to start over? Or is it possible to install a new kernel on this unbootable OS?

Comment: LiveCD + New Kernel files = Fixed OS

Comment: For realz? How do I install the new kernel to the hard drive? I assume a package-manager is out as that will install the kernel for the LiveCD and not my SD card... Do I have to manually compile and set the paths?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is:

- boot from a LiveCD or LiveUSB
- mount filesystems of the broken OS (as a minimum, you need `/` and `/boot` from there) — suppose that they are mounted in `/mnt/tmp`
- mount special filesystems:

  - `mount --bind /dev /mnt/tmp/dev`
  - `mount --bind /proc /mnt/tmp/proc`
  - `mount --bind /sys /mnt/tmp/sys`
- `chroot /mnt/tmp`
- now install whatever packages you need, change other configuration; network will be accessible as set up in the LiveCD environment
- `exit` to leave chroot
- unmount filesystems

In simple cases you may not need the full chroot procedure; package installation, however, most likely needs one (and scripts, especially in kernel-related packages, may need `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`).